# OS X: Schedule Launchctl to quit application at certain time

Tags: macos, launchd

I have created this `launchctl` `.plist` for opening an application at a specific time every day – or the next time the computer *wakes from sleep*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>caffeine-timecontrol.job</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Caffeine.app/Contents/MacOS/Caffeine</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key><integer>40</integer>
            <key>Hour</key><integer>7</integer>
            <key>WeekDay</key><integer>1234567</integer>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The above is supposed to wake app `Caffeine` at `7:40 AM` `Every day`.

However, can I also include a clause to make the application terminate at `00:00 AM` `Every day` if the computer is *awake*?

Meaning, is there an opposite to `StartCalendarInterval`, or would I have to go about it some other way, .e.g. via `crontab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these two methods should work, but I admit I have not tested them:

1. Either you could write an AppleScript a la

`tell application "Caffeine" to quit`

put this in a file, then either launch the file from an `osascript` command or  put it into Script Editor and save it as an application and launch that as a an app

2. or you could use the good old killall command. You would have to lookup the name of process of the Caffeine process and send it a

   `killall Caffeine`

command, assuming that the process name of the Caffeine app is Caffeine (check  it from the Activity monitor or the ps command)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the first method will work nicely whereby `launchctl` runs an AppleScript via `osascript`.